# How to improve performance in visualizing data from database on admin site of django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, performance, django-admin

This are my first steps with django so please take no offense if this seems trivial.

I have a very huge table `mynames` (~ 1 000 000 entrys) and I want to make this table editable in the django admin site. I hooked things up like described in the official django book: I have a model, and I registered it by `admin.site.register(mymodel)`. I can see the "table" on my admin site and I can click on it to see the first page full of names. That is nice so far. As soon as I click on the "show next page button" at the bottom of the page, the query seams to take forever.

Where could the problem be?

### Update:

I added an index to the relevant column and now it is fast. I thought by doing

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

in the model definition there would be an index for this column. But there was none. Only unique index. Is this the way it should be or do I miss something?

Comment: "seams to take forever"?  When you run from the interactive prompt (`>>> from app.models import Class; >>> Class.objects.all()`) how long does it take the database to fetch all 1,000,000 rows?

Comment: @S.Lott: The commands you gave me (I adapted them to my app and my class) promts immediatly the first 25 entrys ore so, and ends in dots, showing there is more, I guess. But if I do `len(Class.objects.all())` it seems to take very, very long...

Comment: How long?  If your query takes forever at the interactive prompt, your database is slow.  You have a MySQL problem, not a Django problem.  Open the MySQL tool and at the SQL> prompt, enter `SELECT * FROM app_class`.  How long does that take?

Comment: @S.Lott, your hints pointed me into the right direction. See my edits. Thank you. I'd like to accept your answer, but you only commented. :-)

Comment: I still don't know what your question is.  It keeps changing.  "Is this the way it should be".  I believe you have proof that it must be that way.  Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#db-index?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to see what the problem is if you pasted your full model class. Is there a specified ordering on the table? If so, you need to create a corresponding index to make pagination on that field fast. Is the list_display attribute set on the ModelAdmin class for the model? By default, django should order the rows based on the primary key so you should not need an additional index. Also check if you have overridden the `__unicode__` method for the model in a way that causes additional database lookups when showing the entity in django admins table?